# Postfix ! (exclamation) operator in C#

Tags: c#

Exploring .NET sources on [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/d58a51f911efb3c98beca21b6cf08cc703424fdf/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs#L5451) I stumbled upon

```
((SomeTypeToCast)variable!).SomeMethodToCall()
```

What's this postfix `!`?

I surmise this is a kind of "this value is never null". However there is no such operator in C# (at least publicly available) and such an expression fails to compile when I try it in a test project.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

This is the *null-forgiving* operator (also known as the "damn-it" operator) in C# 8, which effectively tells the compiler to assume that the value will be non-null. It's a little like a cast, in terms of telling the compiler that you know better than it does - but it has *no* effect at execution time, so you're effectively bypassing the safety of the compiler checks.

It's introduced as part of the [C# 8 nullable-reference type feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references). It *is* available in public preview builds of .NET Core 3.0 SDK.

Typical uses in my experience:

- Testing your argument validation code, to prove that if you *do* pass null into a method, you've got validation to throw `ArgumentNullException`
- Places where you're certain the value won't be null due to other invariants that the compiler isn't aware of. (For example, in Noda Time I have a `ParseResult<T>` which has fields of a value and an exception provider. Either the exception provider is null or the value is null, but never both, and I always check the exception provider before using the value.)